# How to convert PDT time format to this format `2016-09-13 08:56:55 +0000` - using PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

This string `2016-09-13 08:56:55 +0000` - What is the time zone?

How do convert PDT time format `Wed Oct 12 14:40:50 PDT 2016` to this foramt `2016-09-13 08:56:55 +0000`.

I am try:

```
$input_datetime = 'Wed Oct 12 14:40:50 PDT 2016';
$result_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($input_datetime)) . ' +0000';
echo $result_datetime; // 2016-10-12 14:40:50 +0000
```

I don't know about `timezones`. Just I'm making the `datetime` format.
Please update the solutions or suggest.
Thanks for every one!

Comment: +0000 is the time zone. Your conversion makes no sense. Why are the minutes and seconds changing?

Comment: Sorry I don't know about `timezones`. Just I'm making the `datetime` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected output does not make sense to me, because line nogad mentioned, the seconds and minutes change. Please clarify. Meanwhile here the conversion format you wanted:

```
$datestr = 'Wed Oct 12 14:40:50 PDT 2016';
$dt = new DateTime($datestr);
echo $dt->format("Y-m-d\ H:i:s O");
```

Output is:

```
2016-10-12 14:40:50 -0700
```

Comment: What is meaning of `-0700`?

Comment: This is the timezone modifier. It is the difference to Greenwich time (GMT) in hours.

Comment: Thanks! for your help.